# How to update data store in Word docx file

Tags: c#, openxml

I have a Word docx file that has a customXML part to hold data that is used to populate Content Controls.
The customXML part holds an XML file named item.xml, which is a straight and simple XML file with a Root element and some custom elements of mine.
How do I read the XML file, change the element values and see to it the docx is updated properly?
I can get the customXML part with

```
CustomXmlPart part = mainPart.CustomXmlParts.FirstOrDefault();
```

Then I have to get the contents of the item.XML from that part etc. ...

The data binding stuff in document.xml is taken care of, btw.

Answer (score 0):

Easier that I thought, after much thought:

```
CustomXmlPart customXmlPart1 = mainPart.CustomXmlParts.FirstOrDefault();

System.Xml.XmlTextWriter writer = new System.Xml.XmlTextWriter(customXmlPart1.GetStream(System.IO.FileMode.Create),System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);

writer.WriteRaw("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n<Root>\n");
foreach (var val in values) // values is a Dictionary<string,string> of element tag name and element value
{
    writer.WriteRaw( "<" + val.Key + ">" + val.Value + "</" + val.Key + ">\n");
}
writer.WriteRaw( "</Root>");
writer.Flush();
```